# How to to toggle a menu container when clicked on menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in JS. 
I found a mobile menu on codepen but I need to edit it to make it right for what i need. 
Basically, the mobile menu I need to create contains few links that have anchors and redirect users to sections in the page. 
The codepen example I found doesn't close the menu once a link is clicked. I tried to modify the code myself but it doesn't work.

Here the link to the original codepen: https://codepen.io/Gatsby/pen/YdWGgW

And this is the version I did but not working.

```
(function () {
    let header = document.querySelector('.header');
    let icon = document.querySelector('.icon-container');
    let all = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
    icon.onclick = function () {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-open');
    }
    all.onclick = function () {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-open');
    }
}());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` produces an Array so you can't just invoke `onclick` on it, you need a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way :

Basically, you get all of the menu classes, and add an event listener on them to close the menu on each click on any of them

```js
(function() {
  let header = document.querySelector('.header');
  let icon = document.querySelector('.icon-container');
  let menu_item = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
  icon.onclick = function() {
    header.classList.toggle('menu-open');
  }

  var close = function() {
    header.classList.toggle('menu-open');
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < menu_item.length; i++) {
    menu_item[i].addEventListener('click', close, false);
  }

}());
```

```css
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nobile);
 /* Just container/placeholder rulesets - remove once in production */

 body {
   font-family: "Nobile";
   margin: 0 auto;
   line-height: 1.5;
   background: #e0e0e0;
 }

 .container {
   background: #f0f0f0;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 375px;
   height: 600px;
   margin: 50px auto 0;
   box-shadow: 0 0 50px 10px #aaa;
 }

 .container .header {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }

 .content {
   padding: 40px 5% 20px;
   text-align: justify;
   max-height: 100%;
   color: #333;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }

 .content img {
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin: 40px auto 30px;
 }

 @media (max-width: 480px) {
   .container {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     box-shadow: none;
   }
   .container .header {
     position: fixed;
   }
   .content {
     overflow-y: hidden;
   }
 }

 /* End container/placeholder */

 /* Menu Header */

 .header {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 55px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
   position: fixed;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
 }

 .header.menu-open {
   height: 100%;
   background: #111;
   transition: all 0.45s ease-out, background 0.8s ease-out;
 }

 /* Menu List items */

 .mobile-menu {
   clear: both;
 }

 .header ul.menu {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   padding: 0px 40px 0;
   list-style: none;
 }

 .header ul.menu li.menu-item a {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 2.8;
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
 }

 .header ul.menu li.menu-item {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
   margin-top: 5px;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
   transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
   transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
 }

 .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
   transition-delay: 0.35s;
 }

 .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
   transition-delay: 0.3s;
 }

 .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
   transition-delay: 0.25s;
 }

 .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
   transition-delay: 0.2s;
 }

 .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
   transition-delay: 0.15s;
 }

 .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
   transition-delay: 0.1s;
 }

 .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
   transition-delay: 0.05s;
 }

 .header.menu-open ul.menu li.menu-item {
   opacity: 1;
 }

 .header.menu-open ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
   transition-delay: 0.05s;
 }

 .header.menu-open ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
   transition-delay: 0.1s;
 }

 .header.menu-open ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
   transition-delay: 0.15s;
 }

 .header.menu-open ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
   transition-delay: 0.2s;
 }

 .header.menu-open ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
   transition-delay: 0.25s;
 }

 .header.menu-open ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
   transition-delay: 0.3s;
 }

 .header.menu-open ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
   transition-delay: 0.35s;
 }

 /* Menu Icon */

 .icon-container {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   z-index: 2;
   float: right;
   /* Simply change property to float left to switch icon side :) */
   height: 55px;
   width: 55px;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
 }

 .icon-container #menuicon {
   width: 20px;
   height: 10px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin: -4px auto 0;
   top: 50%;
 }

 #menuicon .bar {
   width: 100%;
   height: 1px;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   background: #fff;
   transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
 }

 #menuicon .bar.bar1 {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
   transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
 }

 #menuicon .bar.bar2 {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
   transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
 }

 .menu-open .icon-container {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   transform: rotate(90deg);
 }

 .menu-open .icon-container #menuicon .bar {
   transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
   transition-delay: 0.1s;
 }

 .menu-open .icon-container #menuicon .bar.bar1 {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
   transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
 }

 .menu-open .icon-container #menuicon .bar.bar2 {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
   transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="icon-container">
      <div id="menuicon">
        <div class="bar bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar bar2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Mac</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPad</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPhone</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Watch</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">TV</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Music</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://images.apple.com/v/iphone/home/y/images/overview/hero-iphone-xr_large.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>“With so many trees in the city, you could see the spring coming each day until a night of warm wind would bring it suddenly in one morning. Sometimes the heavy cold rains would beat it back so that it would seem that it would never come and that
      you were losing a season out of your life. This was the only truly sad time in Paris because it was unnatural. You expected to be sad in the fall. Part of you died each year when the leaves fell from the trees and their branches were bare against
      the wind and the cold, wintry light."</p>
    <p><em>- Ernest Hemingway, A Moveable Feast</em></p>

    <img src="https://images.apple.com/v/iphone/home/y/images/overview/film_large.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>"On under the heavy trees of the small town that are a part of your heart if it is your town and you have walked under them, but that are only too heavy, that shut out the sun and dampen the houses for a stranger; out past the last house and on to
      the highway that rose and fell straight away ahead with banks of red dirt sliced cleanly away and the second growth timber on both sides. It was not his country but it was the middle of fall and all of this country was good to drive through and
      to see. "</p>
    <p><em>- Ernest Hemingway, "Fathers and Sons"</em></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here I am using `document.getElementsByClassName` but you could also use `document.querySelectorAll` which is more useful if you want to use more complex selectors

Comment: Thank you @Islam Elshobokshy, it works fine. But how come my code didn't work? I grabbed all the menu.item with querySelectorAll and I made the function all.onclick = function () {header.classList.toggle('menu-open'); }. Where is it wrong? thank you again